# Return number of occurrences based on hour - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I am trying to return the max value grouped by hour. I have tried to achieve this using the following but there are multiple identical hours (groups). I'm hoping to return the max value for each hour only.

```
d = ({
    'Time' : ['0/1/1900 8:00:00','0/1/1900 9:59:00','0/1/1900 10:00:00','0/1/1900 12:29:00','0/1/1900 12:30:00','0/1/1900 13:00:00','0/1/1900 13:02:00','0/1/1900 13:15:00','0/1/1900 13:20:00','0/1/1900 18:10:00','0/1/1900 18:15:00','0/1/1900 18:20:00','0/1/1900 18:25:00','0/1/1900 18:45:00','0/1/1900 18:50:00','0/1/1900 19:05:00','0/1/1900 19:07:00','0/1/1900 21:57:00','0/1/1900 22:00:00','0/1/1900 22:30:00','0/1/1900 22:35:00','1/1/1900 3:00:00','1/1/1900 3:05:00','1/1/1900 3:20:00','1/1/1900 3:25:00'],                 
    'People' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],                      
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Time'] = ['/'.join([str(int(x.split('/')[0])+1)] + x.split('/')[1:]) for x in df['Time']]
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') 

df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='H'),df.People]).size().reset_index(name='count')

print(df)

                  Time  People  count
0  1900-01-01 08:00:00       1      1
1  1900-01-01 09:00:00       1      1
2  1900-01-01 10:00:00       2      1
3  1900-01-01 12:00:00       2      1
4  1900-01-01 12:00:00       3      1
5  1900-01-01 13:00:00       2      2
6  1900-01-01 13:00:00       3      2
7  1900-01-01 18:00:00       2      1
8  1900-01-01 18:00:00       3      3
9  1900-01-01 18:00:00       4      2
10 1900-01-01 19:00:00       2      1
11 1900-01-01 19:00:00       3      1
12 1900-01-01 21:00:00       3      1
13 1900-01-01 22:00:00       3      1
14 1900-01-01 22:00:00       4      2
15 1900-01-02 03:00:00       1      1
16 1900-01-02 03:00:00       2      2
17 1900-01-02 03:00:00       3      1
```

Expected Output:

```
              Time  People  count
0  1900-01-01 08:00:00       1      1
1  1900-01-01 09:00:00       1      1
2  1900-01-01 10:00:00       2      2
3  1900-01-01 12:00:00       2      3
4  1900-01-01 13:00:00       2      3
5  1900-01-01 18:00:00       2      4
6  1900-01-01 19:00:00       2      3
7  1900-01-01 21:00:00       3      3
8  1900-01-01 22:00:00       3      4
9  1900-01-02 03:00:00       1      3
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Each hour of each date? or Each hour of all dates combine?

Comment: @Chris. The dates will go over a day but the times will never overlap if that makes sense. I look at a 20hr timeframe that go over midnight

Comment: @coldspeed, this has been included

Comment: Are you instead looking for `df.groupby(df.Time.dt.floor('H'))['People'].count()`?

Comment: @coldspeed, yep but `max()` instead of `count()`. Thankyou

Comment: OK, your code used `count` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`. Given `df`:

```
                   Time  People
0   1900-01-01 08:00:00       1
1   1900-01-01 09:00:00       1
2   1900-01-01 10:00:00       2
3   1900-01-01 12:00:00       2
4   1900-01-01 12:00:00       3
5   1900-01-01 13:00:00       2
6   1900-01-01 13:00:00       3
7   1900-01-01 18:00:00       2
8   1900-01-01 18:00:00       3
9   1900-01-01 18:00:00       4
10  1900-01-01 19:00:00       2
11  1900-01-01 19:00:00       3
12  1900-01-01 21:00:00       3
13  1900-01-01 22:00:00       3
14  1900-01-01 22:00:00       4
15  1900-01-02 03:00:00       1
16  1900-01-02 03:00:00       2
17  1900-01-02 03:00:00       3
```

`df.groupby('Time')['People'].max()` returns:

```
Time
1900-01-01 08:00:00    1
1900-01-01 09:00:00    1
1900-01-01 10:00:00    2
1900-01-01 12:00:00    3
1900-01-01 13:00:00    3
1900-01-01 18:00:00    4
1900-01-01 19:00:00    3
1900-01-01 21:00:00    3
1900-01-01 22:00:00    4
1900-01-02 03:00:00    3
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris. This may have to be a separate question. But how hard is it to separate this even more. As in return the max value for every 15min segment, instead of every hour.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve more control on the items itselves you could iterate over the single keys of df and get max() value of the other columns, then modify 
 them as you want and later recreate a df. This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Time' : ['0/1/1900 8:00:00','0/1/1900 9:59:00','0/1/1900 10:00:00','0/1/1900 12:29:00','0/1/1900 12:30:00','0/1/1900 13:00:00','0/1/1900 13:02:00','0/1/1900 13:15:00','0/1/1900 13:20:00','0/1/1900 18:10:00','0/1/1900 18:15:00','0/1/1900 18:20:00','0/1/1900 18:25:00','0/1/1900 18:45:00','0/1/1900 18:50:00','0/1/1900 19:05:00','0/1/1900 19:07:00','0/1/1900 21:57:00','0/1/1900 22:00:00','0/1/1900 22:30:00','0/1/1900 22:35:00','1/1/1900 3:00:00','1/1/1900 3:05:00','1/1/1900 3:20:00','1/1/1900 3:25:00'],
    'People' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Time'] = ['/'.join([str(int(x.split('/')[0])+1)] + x.split('/')[1:]) for x in df['Time']]
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')


df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='H'),df.People]).size().reset_index(name='count')

single_times = set(df['Time'])
p, c = [ [] for i in range(2) ]
for v in single_times :
    c.append(max(df.loc[df['Time'] == v]['count']))
    p.append(max(df.loc[df['Time'] == v]['People']))

###make something with c/p

dfdata = {
    'Time' : list(single_times),
    'People' : p,
    'Count' : c
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = dfdata)

print(df2)
```

There could be even faster approaches.